# How to transform list of objects into one row object in java

Tags: java, spring

I have a class A having private members like below.

```
class A {
  String type;
}
```

The above class will come as list objects List . Now  i have Another  class B

```
Class B {
  String type1;
  String type2;
  String type3;
  String type4;
  String type5;
  String type6;
  String type7;
  String type8;
}
```

So  Now How i have to iterate through List  and get the (type(s)) data one by one and then put it into Class B as single object like first one will go to Type1 , second one  ---> type2, third one--- > type3 ....., so on.
Note : There will be only 8 types in class A as a list . so we will have exactly 8 types in Class B and i have thought on reflection so please tell how do i use it, if this is the only option.

Comment: Would you consider replacing  those  eight fields  with an array or a list?

Comment: You could use reflection or simply: `type1 = list.get(0).type; type2 = list.get(1).type;` and so on.

Comment: @Dawood , Yes  i considered but the Class B object will go to Japser reports and it designed to take input like that only.

Comment: Really?  I thought Jasper reports was a whole lot more versatile than that.   OK, then the best thing to do is to write eight simple assignments, as @Flown suggested.  Reflection is overkill here, and you'd have trouble making it  get the fields in the right order.

Comment: @Flown : I cant  do like this  type1 = list.get(0).type; type2 = list.get(1).type .. so on  , but this is good approach , list may contain only one object or two , So please tell how do i do it using reflections.

Comment: Then you should guard it with if statements. `if(list.size() > 0) type1 = list.get(0).type;}` and so on. If you want to do it with reflection then you should teach and try it yourself. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @ Flown : Ok Got It  Thank you AND  i will try using reflections

Comment: Don't do it with reflection.  As I said earlier, it's way more complex than you need, and you will run into all sorts of difficulties, especially around getting the fields in the right order.  Do it the way @Flown suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the class B as:

```
class B
{
    String[] types;
}
```

Then we can do:

```
int i = 0;
for(A aObject:aList){
    bObject.types[i] = aObject.type;
}
```

Else we can add all types like this:

```
bObject.type1 = aList.get(0).type;
bObject.type2 = aList.get(1).type;
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper supports `Map`, so I would suggest you can store the values in a `SortedMap`, such as a `TreeMap` rather than a class with public variables.

Then you would add your type names like this:

```
Map<String, String> b = new TreeMap<>();
b.put("type1", "Foo");
b.put("type2", "Bar");
b.put("type3", "Baz");
...
```

Or if you're populating from a list of A:

```
List<A> list = ...;
Map<String, String> b = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    b.put("type" + (i + 1), list.get(i).type;
}
```

To iterate over all the names in the map, you could then use:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: b.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.key();
    String value = entry.value();
    System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
}
```